# How do I append more conditions to an if statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my own query tool where I want users to be able to pick their own field and attribute and specify whether they want to search for additional parameters such as:

```
('State' === 'California') && ('City' === 'Los Angeles')
```

or

```
('State' === 'California') || ('City' === 'Los Angeles')
```

or

```
(('State' === 'California') && ('City' === 'Los Angeles')) || (('State' === 'Oregon') && ('City' === 'Portland'))
```

This is the line of code that gets the field and attribute and queries the data set by that field and attribute.

```
if(csvStore.getValue(item, $('#fieldsList option:selected').val()) === currentQuery)

{parsing code}
```

However I would like the user to add more conditionals on demand by click an AND button then the code turns into

```
if ((csvStore.getValue(item, $('#fieldsList option:selected').val()) === currentQuery) && (csvStore.getValue(item, $('#fieldsList option:selected').val()) === currentQuery))

{parsing code}
```

But as far as I know you cant append lines of code like you can strings or variables so how would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to add the preferred criteria to array and they query and loop through it to retrieve data from DB?

Comment: Something like `var v; if ((v=foo()) === 1 || v === 2);`

Answer (score 1):

Push the selected values in an array and loop through it. Inside the loop, check for your condition.

```
var fields = new Array();

$("#fieldsList").each(function(){
    fields.push($('#fieldsList option:selected').val());
});
for (var i = 0; i <= fields.length; i++) {
        if(csvStore.getValue(item, fields[i]) === currentQuery){
            // {parsing code}
        }
}
```